# What image file type is expected by Matlab Stereo Camera Calibrator app?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

The Matlab Calibration Workflow documention just says "capture images."
But it doesn't say how, or what file format is required.

My Matlab script has the line:
load('handshakeStereoParams.mat');
...and this .mat file I believe is generated by Matlab's Stereo Camera Calibrator app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mathworks documentation on the [Stereo Camera Calibration app](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-camera-calibrator-app.html) does give specific advice on image formats:

> Use uncompressed images or lossless compression formats such as PNG.

There's also a great deal more information on the details of what sort of images you need, under the "Image, Camera, and Pattern Preparation" subheading, in the expandable sections.

Answer (score 0):

"Capture images" means take images of the checkerboard pattern with the cameras that you are trying to calibrate. Generally, you can load images of any format that `imread` can read into the Stereo Camera Calibrator app. However, it is much better not to use a format with lossy compression, like JPEG, because the calibration artifacts affect the calibration accuracy.  So if you can configure your camera to save the images as PNG or BMP, you should do that. And if your camera only lets you use JPEG, then turn the image quality up to 100%.